# What does the coef_ values in LinearRegression() stand for?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

am a beginner in machine learning. It is just a simple question, what does the coef_ in LinearRegression() represent? I know it stands for coefficient but i dont understand the values, does high and positive coef_ mean stronger relation?

And also, if the coef_ values are in exponential, does that mean that my LinearRegression is wrong?

```
array([-3.12840684e+02, -1.01279891e+13, -1.42682874e+13, -1.42682874e+13,
   -1.42682873e+13, -1.42682873e+13, -1.23057091e+04, -6.08730443e+02,
   -2.25836847e+12, -2.25836846e+12, -2.25836846e+12, -2.25836846e+12,
   -2.25836845e+12, -2.25836846e+12, -2.25836846e+12, -2.25836847e+12,
   -2.25836849e+12,  5.41669310e+11,  5.41669341e+11,  5.41669325e+11,
    2.47680574e+12,  5.41669172e+11,  5.41669322e+11,  5.41669336e+11,
    5.41669320e+11, -1.92388659e+12, -1.92388658e+12, -1.92388659e+12,
   -1.92388654e+12, -1.43004842e+12, -1.92388655e+12, -1.92388658e+12,
   -1.92388665e+12, -1.92388657e+12, -1.92388658e+12, -1.92388653e+12,
   -1.92388658e+12, -1.92388660e+12, -1.92388658e+12, -1.92388660e+12,
   -9.83609518e+11, -9.83609497e+11, -9.83609551e+11, -9.83609529e+11,
   -1.47744767e+12, -9.83609560e+11, -9.83609506e+11, -9.83609465e+11,
   -9.83609519e+11, -9.83609455e+11, -9.83609513e+11, -9.83609555e+11,
   -9.83609535e+11, -9.83609497e+11, -9.83609511e+11, -9.83609514e+11,
   -1.54590339e+13, -1.54590339e+13, -1.54590339e+13, -1.54590339e+13,
   -1.30678844e+12, -1.30678843e+12, -1.30678843e+12, -1.30678847e+12,
   -1.30678844e+12, -1.62361585e+13, -1.62361585e+13, -1.62361585e+13,
   -1.62361585e+13, -1.62361586e+13, -1.62361585e+13,  5.88718912e+12,
    5.88718906e+12,  5.88718908e+12,  5.88718907e+12, -5.88718905e+12,
   -5.88718905e+12, -5.88718906e+12, -5.88718904e+12,  3.45085841e+11,
    3.45085830e+11,  3.45085861e+11,  3.45085814e+11,  3.45085829e+11,
    3.45085830e+11,  3.11126022e+12,  3.11126021e+12,  3.11126021e+12,
    1.13335966e+07,  3.11126021e+12, -7.58191433e+11, -7.58191424e+11,
    3.04834491e+03,  3.74262207e+03, -1.19176646e+04, -1.16855749e+04,
    2.00192065e+03,  3.75148918e+12,  3.75148916e+12,  3.75148918e+12,
    3.75148928e+12,  2.24187815e+13,  2.24187815e+13,  2.24187815e+13,
    2.24187815e+13,  6.26624305e+04,  1.61187017e+04,  2.00000527e+04,
   -3.10534619e+03,  2.39790901e+04, -7.55683101e+12, -7.55683096e+12,
   -7.55683096e+12, -7.55683096e+12, -7.55683097e+12, -7.55683097e+12,
    2.32335100e+13,  2.32335100e+13,  2.32335100e+13, -1.15363807e+13,
   -1.15363808e+13, -1.15363807e+13, -1.15363807e+13, -1.15363807e+13,
    2.70555822e+12,  2.70555822e+12,  2.70555823e+12, -3.19955267e+11,
   -3.19955228e+11, -3.19955165e+11, -3.19955294e+11, -3.19955247e+11,
   -3.19955264e+11, -3.19955255e+11, -3.19955270e+11, -3.19955263e+11,
   -4.86759426e+12, -4.86759423e+12, -4.86759425e+12, -4.86759428e+12,
   -4.86759425e+12, -4.86759427e+12])
```

Comment: The coef_ gives the coefficient of the features of your dataset. Also, e just signifies the 10th power associated with the number

Comment: So does that mean that all the variable used in the linear regression has a meaningful impact? since all the features have a high value

Comment: I don't know about the output of your LR but technically speaking its the case, also if you find the dimension of the array and dimension of the input data it will be same, however, you can use LASSO to suppress the feature which is not important.

Comment: What am doing here is just using categorical variables to predict a continuous variable, in this case "Price". I dummied the data for the categorical variables that i think may contribute to the prediction of "Price". Do you think LASSO will be able to deal with categorical variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coef_ gives you an array of weights estimated by linear regression. It is of shape (n_targets, n_features). In your case it is 1D array as you only have one target.

In your case weights has huge values, make sure you normalize your features and use regularization for your model.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its wise to atleast read the header page of the scikit learn module you are using.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html
For a linear regression:
$\hat{y}(w, x) = w_0 + w_1 x_1 + ... + w_p x_p$

Across the module, we designate the vector of coefficients \w as coef_ and as intercept_.